# Exercise 2.36 in 'Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms' (Hubbard)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an n by n diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_n$, and suppose that one of the diagonal entries, say $\lambda_k$, satisfies $inf_{k\neq j}|\lambda_k - \lambda_j| \geq m > 0$ for some number $m$. Let $B$ be an n by n matrix. Find a number $R$, depending on $m$, such that if $|B| < R$, then Newton's method will converge if it is used to solve

$(A+B)\vec x = \mu \vec x$, for $\vec x$ satisfying $|\vec x|^2 = 1$,

starting at $\vec x_0 = \vec e_k$, $\mu_0 = \lambda_k.$

---

This exercise appears in the chapter review for Chapter 2: Solving equations. At this point, the book has presented Kantorovich's theorem as well as the inverse and implicit function theorems (constructive versions making use of Kantorovich's theorem to show Newton's method converges). My approach is to use the implicit function theorem to prove convergence, and to do so (this is where I get lost) find an $R$, such that $|B| < R$, which satisfies the Kantorovich inequality $$\frac 1{2|\mathbf f(\vec x_0)||[\mathbf {Df}'(\vec x_0)]^{-1}|^2} \geq M$$ where $\mathbf f$ depends on $\vec x$, $\mu$ and the diagonal entries of $A$, and is vector-valued with entries $(A+B-\mu I)\vec x$, $|\vec x|^2 - 1$ and $A$. $M$ is a (local) Lipschitz ratio on $\mathbf {Df}$. Help would be greatly appreciated.